# Flutter - Why onVerticalDragEnd does not work?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I am trying to get if the user is swiping horizontally or vertically using a GestureDetector widget. For some reason I am unable to make the onVerticalDragEnd property work. HorizontalDragEnd works just fine.

Am I supposed to add anything else?

`

```
child: new GestureDetector(
                  onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
                    print("horizontal drag");
                  },
                  onVerticalDragEnd : (DragEndDetails details) {
                    print("vertical drag");
                  } ,
                  child: new GridView.count(..
```

`

Comment: You most likely have another widget somewhere that catch this gesture. Such as `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

Try logging when your GestureDetector and/or parent components are being created, and see if it's being re-rendered before the End event.  I had the same problem, and it was due to side effects of the Update event I used causing a re-render.  After making some modifications to prevent that from happening, the End event started working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of GestureDetector, you can use Listener, it worked for me. Here's how I implemented it -

```dart
import 'dart:math';
```

```dart
double radians(double degree) {
    return ((degree * 180) / pi);
  }
```

```dart
void swipe(moveEvent) {
double angle = radians(moveEvent.delta.direction);
    if (angle >= -45 && angle <= 45) {
      print("Swipe Right");
    } else if (angle >= 45 && angle <= 135) {
      print("Swipe Down");
    } else if (angle <= -45 && angle >= -135) {
      print("Swipe Up");
    } else {
      print("Swipe Left");
    }
}
```

```dart
child: Listener(
  onPointerMove: (moveEvent) => swipe(moveEvent),
  child: GridView.count(...),
)
```

But this calls function multiple times on a single swipe

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GridView widget is catching the vertical drag gesture. May not be an optimal solution, but by making GestureDetector widget as a parent for EACH GridView child, I was able to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Good day,

The reason this did not work is because you cannot specify `onHorizontalDrag` and `onVerticalDrag` at the same time. Doing so will result in one of the recognizer being ignored. In this case, it seems as though the vertical gesture was ignored in favor of horizontal.

Ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/03a1f4acb315bd5cd99c5cafe19a4875f9f98422/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/gesture_detector.dart#L187

Hopes this clears things up for you :)

Comment: If I delete onHorizontalDrag it still doesn't execute the vertical one. Furthermore, both horizontal and vertical drag work together just fine if I don't use GridView as a child. Is this a bug or just a constraint?

Comment: The reason it works is because you are using a grid view :P